# Modify sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How do i fill my 'email' column with 'emp_fname' and 'emp_lname' and also eliminate spaces for multiple first names eg: Ben John Davis -----> benjohn.davis@mail.com....I can only do an update but not a permanent modification
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2QlR.png)

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  The logic doesn't make sense (why would `email` have names in it?) and the statement "I can only do an update not a permanent modification" shows such a large misunderstanding of SQL commands that it is indecipherable.

Answer (score 0):

You can update previous data. And you can do it in insert

Update:

```
UPDATE table_name SET email = CONCAT(REPLACE(emp_fname, ' ', ''), emp_lnmae, '@mail.com');
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(email, other_fields) VALUES(CONCAT(REPLACE(emp_fname_value, ' ', ''), emp_fname_value, '@mail.com'), other_fields_value);
```